# Converting string to double "cuts" 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with converting string to double, it works fine when I run it on my local machine but when I deploy it to the server it "cuts" 0 in front.
For example I have a string value of 0,0123 and when I convert it to double I get 123.
I use [ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) with [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#), method I use is `Convert.ToDouble()` and the hosting is somee.com.

Right now I just divide the number by 10000 and get what I need, but as you can imagine it's not prefect solution so maybe someone has better idea of how to solve it.

Comment: 00123 and 123 are the same exact number

Comment: depending on culture, a comma in some cultures can mean the a decimal point.  So #13amon is right, but depends upon culture.  Does you figure represent 0.0123.  In which case you need to take culture into account when you do your convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your machine and the server are using two different cultures.

Some cultures use "." as a decimal point, while others use ",".
It seems that in your server culture, "." is the decimal point - and so the comma in "0,0123" is treated as a thousands separator instead.

I would use the overload for `double.TryParse` or `Convert.ToDouble` that takes an `IFormatProvider` and pass in the correct `CultureInfo`.

In the future, try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to format all your internal data (i.e. data persistence, or data flowing within your system), and use the proper `CultureInfo` for displaying data to the user.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about that, it work's fine now :)

Comment: To be clear, the comma isn't ignored, but treated as a thousands separator.

Comment: Nice catch @SimonSvensson, i've udpated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The decimal point is not the same across cultures and, therefore, computers with different culture setting.

Try using `double.Parse(string, CultureInfo)` with an explicit `CultureInfo` that works for your format.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you express your value as 0,0123 rather than 0.0123, I would guess the language/culture settings on the server are different than on your own machine.

Try printing out the result of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` from somewhere on the server, and compare it to what your local machine produces.